# Choosing forward propagating observation in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr

I am working with a dataset like this:
There is the participant ID and then there is the date of the exam and the date of biopsy. There are multiple observations per participant.

The dataset looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
date_of_exam = c("2020-05-03", "2020-07-08", "2020-04-12", "2020-04-01", "2020-03-12", "2020-08-12", "2020-08-10", "2020-09-12", "2020-10-01"),
date_of_biopsy = c("2020-05-01", "2020-07-06", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-03", "2020-03-09", "2020-08-15", "2020-08-09", "2020-09-14", "2020-10-05"))
```

Whenever the date of exam is before the date of biopsy (date_of_exam minus date_of_biopsy < 0), I want to use the next higher date of the exam.

How can I create a forloop or else that checks the condition (date_of_exam minus date_of_biopsy <0) and if this is true it chooses the next higher value of the exam, checks this again for the condition (date_of_exam minus date_of_biopsy <0) and if it is not met, takes this value or else chooses the next higher value...?

I was thinking about creating multiple
ifelse conditions in dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  mutate(exam_2nd_value = ifelse(test=(df$data_of_exam-df_date_of_biopsy<0)==TRUE, yes=df$date_of_exam[min(n(), 2)],no=df$date_of_exam[min(n(),1)]))%>%
ungroup()
```

And then some more if else, but I feel like this is not a good way and is probably not going to work.

Also, when I use the code mentioned above, I get this error:

Error: Problem with mutate() input new. x Input new can't be recycled to size 3

Can you tell me why I get this error and what I can do to solve my problem?

Thanks a lot,

Phil

Comment: In the example data, it seems none of B's exams happened after the 2020-04-15 biopsy. Could you please add expected output from your sample data?

Comment: Thanks Jon, for your comment!

Comment: Thanks Jon, for your comment! The expected output: A: 2020-05-03, A: 2020-07-08, B: 2020-03-12, C: 2020-08-10. A should be returned twice because it satisfied the condition in two cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding the problem correctly, something like this should work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(date_of_exam = as.Date(date_of_exam),
         date_of_biopsy = as.Date(date_of_biopsy)) %>%
  arrange(date_of_exam) %>%
  mutate(lead_exam_date = lead(date_of_exam),
         exam_2nd_value = if_else(date_of_exam>date_of_biopsy,
                                  date_of_exam,
                                  lead_exam_date)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Explanation

1. group by ID
2. convert all strings to date objects (which internally are just epoch times and thus can be added/subtracted like numbers)
3. arrange by date in each group (lowest first)
4. use `lead` to shift the `date_of_exam` column up by one for each group
5. do the comparison you want, if exam date is greater than biopsy date (eg former in the future relative to latter), use the current exam date, otherwise use the next exam date (the one created using `lead`)

This will give you:

```
  ID    date_of_exam date_of_biopsy lead_exam_date exam_2nd_value
  <chr> <date>       <date>         <date>         <date>        
1 B     2020-03-12   2020-03-09     2020-04-01     2020-03-12    
2 B     2020-04-01   2020-04-03     2020-04-12     2020-04-13    
3 B     2020-04-12   2020-04-15     NA             NA            
4 A     2020-05-03   2020-05-01     2020-07-08     2020-05-03    
5 A     2020-07-08   2020-07-06     NA             2020-07-08    
6 C     2020-08-10   2020-08-09     2020-08-12     2020-08-10    
7 C     2020-08-12   2020-08-15     2020-09-12     2020-09-13    
8 C     2020-09-12   2020-09-14     2020-10-01     2020-10-02    
9 C     2020-10-01   2020-10-05     NA             NA
```

I'm not sure based on the way the original problem is framed what to do if there is no next exam date (hence the NAs). To deal with those, `lead` has a `default` argument which will be supplied when there is no next value.

As far as the errors you encountered, I couldn't reproduce the error you got but instead I got an error for trying to subtract two strings (the two dates in the `mutate` call). Yours might be the same thing just expressed a different way due to version differences or something.

Additionally, you can't use `ifelse` here because this function isn't vectorized; you need `if_else` which takes entire vectors rather than scalers (the name is super confusing).

Finally, I don't think the calls to the original dataframe with `df$` would have worked since those aren't aware of the grouping you imposed earlier in the chain.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much. Thank you very much as well for the explanations! Helps a beginner like me to learn a lot.